# using \b in regex

Tags: python, regex

--SOLVED--
I solved my issue by enabling multiline mode, and now the characters ^ and $ work perfectly for identifying the beginning and end of each string

--EDIT--

My code:

```
import re
import test_regex


def regex_content(text_content, regex_dictionary):

#text_content = text_content.lower()
regex_matches = []

# Search sanitized text (markup removed) for DLP theme keywords
for key,value in regex_dictionary.items():

  # Get confiiguration settings
  min_matches = value.get('min_matches',1)
  risk = value.get('risk',1)
  enabled = value.get('enabled',False)
  regex_str = value.get('regex','')

  # Fast compute True/False hit for each DLP theme word
  if enabled:
    print "Searching for key : %s" % (key)
    my_regex = re.compile(value.get('regex'))
    hits = my_regex.findall(text_content)

    if len(hits) > 0:
      regex_matches.append((key, risk, len(hits), hits))

# Return array of results (key, risk, number of hits, regex matches)
return regex_matches

def main():


    #print defaults.test_regex.dlp_regex

    text_content = ""

    for line in open('testData.txt'):
        text_content+=line

    for match in regex_content(text_content, test_regex.dlp_regex):
        print "\nFound %s : %s" % (match[0], match[3])

    print "\n"

if __name__ == '__main__':
main()
```

and it is using the regex found here:

```
'Large number of US Zip Codes' : { 'regex' : "\b\d{5}(?:-\d{1,4})?\b"},
```

When I precede my regex with the 'r' flag, I can find the zip codes I'm looking for, but as well as every other 5 digit number in my document I am searching through. From my understanding this is because it ignored the \b characters. Without the r flag though, it cannot find any zip codes. It works perfectly fine in regexr, but not in my code. I haven't had any luck making \b characters work, nor ^ and $ for identifying the beginnings and ends of the strings I'm searching for. What is it that I am misunderstanding about these special characters?

--Original post--

I am writing a regex for identifying zip codes (and only zip codes), so to avoid false positives I am trying to include a boundary on my regex, using both of the following:

```
\b\d{5}\b|\b\d{5}-\b\d{1,4}\b
```

using the online regex debugger Regexr, my code should correctly catch 5 digit zip codes, such as 34332. However, I have two problems:
1. This regex is not working in my actual code for finding any zip codes, but it does work when I don't have the boundary (\b) characters. The exact code I'm trying to extract with my regex is:

```
Zip: 
----
98839-0111
34332
```

2. I don't see why my regex can't correctly identify 98839-0111 in Regexr. I tried doing the super-primitive approach of

```
\b\d{5}\b|98839-0111
```

and even that couldn't identify 98839-0111. Does anyone know what could be going on?

Note: I have also tried using ^ and $ for the boundaries of my regex, but this also doesn't find the regex's, not even in Regexr.

EDIT: After removing the first part of my regex, leaving only

```
98839-0111
```

It can now correctly identify it. I guess this means that once a string is pulled out by one of my regex's, it can no longer be found by any subsequent regexs? Why is this?

Comment: Both `re.search(r'\b\d{5}\b|98839-0111', '98839-0111')` and `re.search(r'\b\d{5}\b|\b\d{5}-\b\d{1,4}\b', '98839-0111')` succeed for me in Python 2.7.6.  Could you show the exact code that uses these regexes?

Comment: I'm never a fan of `\b` as a word boundary.  It's not portable.  Instead, you might try using the proper classes, `[[:<:]]` and `[[:>:]]`.  You'll find them documented in [**`man re_format`**](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=re_format&sektion=7)

Comment: @ghoti: `[[:<:]]` and `[[:>:]]` are not classes but only aliases for `(?<!\w)\b` and `\b(?!\w)`. Not sure this is available in python.

Comment: I edited my original post to include my code

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte, righto, strings inside `[:` and `:]` are normally classes, but these word boundaries are "special cases" according to `man re_format`.  But I would disagree that they are aliases as you describe, unless you just mean that they're "functionally equivalent".  They may not be POSIX.2 compliant, but in my experience they're more widely available than `\b`.  I too am not sure about python's RE parser. Lack of support for these bracket expressions would seem to me to be a fail, but perhaps I'm just too old-school.  :-/

Comment: The updated code in the edit does not show what you actually have in 'testData.txt', and what other transformations you do. It looks like a separate question.

Comment: The rest of my testData.txt is sensitive and I cannot post it on a public forum. It simply contains a list filled with regex's and other properties unique to each key. 

the basic format:
`dlp_regex = {
    'Large number of US Zip Codes2' : { 'regex' : "\b(\d{5}-\d{4}|\d{5})\b", 'min_matches' : 100, 'enabled':True,'risk': 1},
}

all_dictionaries = {}
all_dictionaries['config_dlp_regex'] = dlp_regex`

note: I am not using "min matches" anywhere in my implementation as of yet.

Comment: Without more specific input data, I am afraid no one can help you. You only gave us `98839-0111`, and `34332`, so we deduced that you need to match either 5 digits or 5 digits + hyphen + 4 digits. Now, are you going to change the requirements? This is not fine.

Comment: @ghoti: no you are not too old-school, for POSIX.2 engines `[[:<:]]` and `[[:>:]]` are build-in word boundaries and not aliases, but it is no more the case for example with PCRE where it's only a conveniant way to write `\b(?=\w)` and `\b(?<=\w)` (my mistake, it was not with negative lookarounds) and they are converted to this.

Answer (score 6):

It is because of the alternative list: the first part was matched, and the engine stopped checking.

Try [this regex](https://regex101.com/r/iU5yQ8/2)

```
98839-0111|\b\d{5}\b
```

And you'll get a match.

Or, to be more generic in your case:

```
\b(?:\d{5}-\d{4}|\d{5})\b
```

will match both, and more (actually, functionally the same as `\b\d{5}(?:-\d{4})?\b`). [See demo](https://regex101.com/r/iU5yQ8/3).

Comment: and by extension, `\b\d{5}-\b\d{1,4}\b|\b\d{5}\b`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex:

```
\b(\d{5}-\d{1,4}|\d{5})\b
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/fX3lE0/2)**

Comment: This assumes that all zip codes are not among other text on a line. I don't think you can make that assumption.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I assumed that from OP statement `I am writing a regex for identifying zip codes (and only zip codes)` :)

Comment: Yes, but that doesn't mean that the zipcode is on a line by their own.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I actually assume it is in a single line from OP's input sample. He put 2 zip codes, I based in that to do my answer.

Comment: Then document that assumption, perhaps ask for feedback on the question.

Comment: Marjin is correct, I cannot assume I will have them on a line on their own

Answer (score 0):

Your pattern is evaluated for each position in the string from the left to the right, so if the left branch of your pattern succeeds, the second branch isn't tested at all.

I suggest you to use this pattern that solves the problem:

```
\b\d{5}(?:-\d{1,4})?\b
```